# Intersection of Probability measures

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $X$ be a metric space with Borel $\sigma$-algebra $B(X)$ and suppose that $\mathbb{P}_1$ and $\mathbb{P_2}$ are two probability measures on $(X,B(X))$.

Question:  Suppose $G$ is an open set contained in $X$, what does the following mean:
$$
 \mathbb{P}_1(G) \cap \mathbb{P}_2(G)  ?
$$

I am sure my confusion on this point stems from a misconception regarding the probability.  Initially I thought that one could think of a probability measure as a map 
$$
\mathbb{P}_i: B(X) \longrightarrow  [0,1]
$$
Where each $B \in B(X)$ is mapped to a point $x \in [0,1]$, however this means that the intersection  $\mathbb{P}_1(G) \cap \mathbb{P}_2(G)   $ doesn't make much sense (just $x$ if $\mathbb{P_1}(G) = \mathbb{P}_2(G)$ and $0$ otherwise).  Is it in fact the case that the probability measure $\mathbb{P}_i$ is a map
$$\mathbb{P}_i : B(X) \longrightarrow [0,1]$$
*but* each $B \in B(X)$ is mapped to a subset, $S$, of $[0,1]$ such that $\mathbb{P}(S) = x$ where $\mathbb{P}$ is the usual Lebesgue measure on the unit interval?

Comment: Where did you encounter this notation?

Comment: We will never know, it seems...